# Deploying Angular Project to CPanel return eror Cors-Policy: no Access-Control Allow-Origin Header present in request source

Tags: angular, cpanel

it's been my first time to deploying an angular app on an online server. it isn't an enterprise things tbh. during deployment, i used this command

```
ng build --baseHref=https://www.exampleUrl.com/ --deployUrl=https://www.exampleUrl.com/
```

then i upload it to CPanel.

1. at the first few minutes, i can see my web online with absolute url "www.exampleUrl.com" in my PC's but the app cannot be accessed by mobile devices (idk to see console log in mobile devices so i can't provide the log issues).
2. after an hour, it return this error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.exampleUrl.com/ngx_pagespeed_beacon?url=https%3A%2F%2FexampleUrl.com%2F' from origin 'https://exampleUrl.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

followed by

```
www.exampleUrl.com/ngx_pagespeed_beacon?url=https%3A%2F%2FexampleUrl.com%2F:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

i have been surfing through whole related tag in this forum but none of them works for me. any comment would be really appreciated!

btw, here's my package.json and angular.json (idk maybe you guys need to observe these)

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.7.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.2"
  }
}
```

**angular.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "f6871353-1796-4510-ac5d-c072d98cf307"
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myproject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myproject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myproject:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myproject:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "myproject"
}
```

Comment: Basically this is a server side error, there's a JS library called `cors` that can be used in `express.js` to solve such problem, and every backend framework has such a thing.

Now if you were looking to solve this at your end (*Which isn't recommended*) please read this article https://www.positronx.io/handle-cors-in-angular-with-proxy-configuration/ to learn how to set up an `Angular Proxy`.

Comment: thanks for your feedback :). hmm, i didn't yet creating my backend on my project. should i create my backend before i push it again to my cpanel page? because my understanding about backend such nodejs still low hm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are no `HTTP` requests but still, you are getting `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Well, in this case:

1. Login to your `cPanel` control panel.
2. Under the `FILES` section, click on the `File Manager` option.
3. Go to the `public_html` folder.
4. Show hidden files from the settings.
5. If you have an existing `.htaccess` file, you will see it in the `public_html` folder.
6. Right click on the `.htaccess` file and click on the `Edit` menu.
7. Add the following line

   `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
8. Save.

Now in case in `step 5` you didn't have a `.htaccess`:

5-1. Click on the New File option in the top left corner.

5-2. Write the file name as `.htaccess` in the New File Name: field and click on the `Create New File` button.

5-3. Now you can write or edit `.htaccess` file. (Go to `step 7`).

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a server error where the angular app is getting it resources/data from. To resolve this go to backend code base and add the domain of where the angular app is deployed to to the list of allowed host, depending on the language and framework you are using you can research how to add allowed host or install a cors package to the project depending on the language or framework been used on the backend.

Comment: Thank's william, yeah now i understand why it happened. i create a really ugly backend with nodeJS and looks like my backend is not running properly (i used npx express-generator) ... but i got a better understanding tbh :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the server you use, you need to allow the domain where the request if originating from to make requests to the server in question.

To allow all, you will do something like "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*"

The "*" option allows requests from all domains, you can specify specific domains as well. It is a better practice not to allow requests from all domains.

Below is an extract from one of my old projects written in Java and running on Jetty Server.

return responseBuilder.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();

Comment: hmmm, i guess it was backend problem, but since  i am not using backend then i should now. hmhmhm but thanks anyway :)